# How does Blazor Webassembly app know which user has been logged in server side?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have created a new Blazor WebAssembly project with a separate API project. My WebAssembly project will
query this WebAPI for data.

I have included `Identity` in my app and this seems to work. I can register a new user and use the below code to log in a user on my Web API.

Code used to log someone in:

```
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

     if (result.Succeeded)
     {
         //I arrive here, so login was succesful
         return true;
     }
```

So Identity seems to be working.

What I'm wondering now is:

1. my user logs on in the web assembly app
2. this app uses HttpClient to send a request to my server to authenticate the user, using a username and password
3. the server checks the username and password and uses `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password)` which works
4. How does my client know which user has been authenticated? How can I display more information about this user, check his roles, ...

Does anyone have any guidance or best practices on this please?

Answer (score 1):

Since Blazor WASM is entirely executed on the client, there are two different authentication models: **Cookies** and **Token**. (There are more). The basic idea, though, is the same. With each HTTP request sent by `HttpClient`, an additional header is sent to the server.

Personally, I think Token authentication is a much smarter way supported in different libraries and can be implemented very quickly.

In a nutshell:
With a token-based approach - to be more precise with OpenId Connect -,, you provide an identity service, and your Blazor application will become a client. The token, unlike a cookie, can be read easily by a client. If configured properly, it contains information (claims) like the user's name or email address.
The identity service is an MVC/Razor page application with special libraries handling the authentication flow.

The authentication flow (very, very briefly):
A user wants to login into your Blazor application. If there is no token available, the authentication process starts. The Blazor application redirects the user to the "authentication flow" part of your identity service. It is an endpoint without any "visual" result. The result is another redirect to your MVC/Razor page login view. You can implement any authentication logic here. If the user has been authenticated successfully (based on your logic), the user is redirected back to your Blazor application with a valid token in the URL. This token is extracted and can be used to access an API.

It sounds a bit complicated, and it is a lot to learn and understand. However, you will get a reliable, widely used, and safe way to do authentication and authorization.

As a starting point for reading

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/0_overview.html
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html#login-workflow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-5.0